# Wix Corvid Database Filtering Conditional

Tags: database, frontend, velo

I have setup a filter using the code queen video-works great except one part-

I got two dropdowns,

Category and subcategory,I am trying to setup simple conditional filtering

When I click category, on change event happens -> subcategory gets activated(this is working)

Subcategory should conditionally filter and show only relevant/matching results,however shows all the results from the field.

For eg.  Category dropdown we choose - industrial houses -> Subcategory becomes active and shows only the results that match for the industrial category

Currently shows every element from the field,can anyone help me?

Here is the code.Thank you

```
$w.onReady(function () {  //code that clears the search
  $w('#clear').onClick(() => {
      $w('#dropdown1 , #dropdown2 , #dropdown3, #dropdown4, #dropdown5 , #dropdown6').value = "";
      $w('#dataset1').setFilter(wixData.filter())
        .then();
    });
});

export function button1_click(event, $w) { //filter on click even

let searchValue = $w("#locationSearch").value;

  $w("#dataset1").setFilter(wixData.filter()

 .contains("bathrooms",$w('#dropdown1').value)
 .contains("bedrooms", $w('#dropdown2').value)
 .contains("typesOfProperties", $w('#dropdown5').value) //CATEGORY DROPDOWN
 .eq("subcategory", $w("#dropdown6").value) //SUBCATEGORY DROPDOWN
  .contains('propertyAddress', searchValue)
  .contains('averagePrice', $w('#dropdown7').value))

      .then((results) => {
      console.log("Dataset is now Filtered");
      $w("#repeater1").data = results.items;
     })
   .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
  });      

 $w("#repeater1").expand();}

//FILTER FROM THE CODE QUEEN VIDEO THAT SHOULD SHOW ONLY MATCHING RESULTS

export function dropdown5_change(event, $w) {
SubCatFilter(); }
function SubCatFilter (){
$w("#dropdown6").enable();  //SUBCATEGORY DROPDOWN
$w("#dataset1").setFilter(wixData.filter()  //BOTH FIELDS IN THE SAME DATASET

.eq("subcategory", $w("#dropdown5").value)  //SUBCATEGORY KEY FIELD 
)
}
```